# Access to Akka actor outside

Tags: scala, servlet-filters, akka

I take *Akka 2.0* and want to use it inside my web application. For this i create `Filter` to run an `ActorSystem` on filter inits.

Filter loads, starts Akka kernel `Bootable` implementation.

Now i create an Actor (for user authentication) and want to send a message to it at other part of application outside of scope my akka filter. Is any way to do this (i see only making some `object` to hold system `val`)? Maybe my logic to use Akka in this way is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to create and destroy the ActorSystem and set it as an [attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) on your ServletContext (make a small façade to get it and set it perhaps?) Then just obtain it from the ServletContext within your Filter.

Comment: Thanks, I wait you answer =). i want to get system not in web part (not in other filters or servlets). I have ssh daemon, which runs outside of web part and i want to send a message from within. I see two varians: 1. use other system in sshd and obtain remote actor ref 2. make an object with system. What do you think?

Comment: How does it run outside the web part? What creates it? Make sure you have a clear place where your application is created, so dependencies can be sensibly passed in.

Comment: Web part is a lift. From Boot class i start sshd in other thread (this is what i mean with outside, sry for misundestanding).

Comment: Seems that i need to use system in Boot and shutdown it with lift. For now it will be ok, but if i want to split this parts in near future need other solution.